# Learning French in France

Tags: france

I want to travel to France to learn French.  Language schools are prohibitvely expensive.  Are there any reasonable priced schools?

I am interested in northern France (Lille or Hauts de France) but I can travel to any other area if the school and fees are good

Comment: It would be good if you mention your budget. Compared to where I live Northern France is very cheap...

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a travel-specific question.